# Trying to add Multiple languages in my Android App

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I make a simple android App which have a Login activity and one fragment(BottomSheetDialogFragment) I am trying to add multiple languages through the fragment (which have multiple buttons) to main activity(Login Activity) but its not working here below the code can some one help me please?

**Login Activity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ActivityLoginBinding binding;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        binding.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bottomnav bottomnav=new bottomnav();
                bottomnav.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),bottomnav.getTag());

            }
        });


    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class bottomnav extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottomnav, container, false);
        Button urdu,hindi,arabic,eng;
        eng=view.findViewById(R.id.english);
        urdu=view.findViewById(R.id.urdu);
        hindi=view.findViewById(R.id.hindi);
        arabic=view.findViewById(R.id.arabic);
        eng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        return view;

        }

    private void setlocale(String language) {
        Locale locale= new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.english:
                setlocale("");

                break;
            case R.id.urdu:
                setlocale("ur");

                break;
            case R.id.hindi:
                setlocale("hi");

                break;
            case R.id.arabic:
                setlocale("ar");

                break;

            default:
        }
}
}
```

[Login activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lohv8.png)
[Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSQw7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the activity for the language changes to apply